# Page Method calls from jQuery to Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, asp.net, url, sharepoint-2010, pagemethods

I have an application page (aspx) deployed in the `_LAYOUTS` folder of MS SharePoint 2010.

I would like to call a method inside that page marked with the `[WebMethod]` attribute using jQuery. I am using the following code on `document.ready()`:

```
$("#btnOk").click(function () {
    var theUrl = '/_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod';
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: theUrl,
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            [...]
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            [...]
        }
    });
});
```

This code unfortunately does not work. The problem is with the URL: in fact it works if I use an absolute URL like this

```
var theUrl = 'http://server/sites/xxx/_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod';
```

How can I transform my path in an absolute one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod
```

in your example is equivalent to:

```
http://server/_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod
```

that is your problem.  starting with / means start at the root.  You should adjust this.  If it has to be somehow dynamic because it can be used multiple places, you may need to use the codebehind to inject the path or something.  If this is always run from a static place, just modify the url.

If the page you're running it from is, for instance:

```
http://server/sites/xxx/Somepage.aspx
```

Then just change it to

```
_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod
```

with no slash.

If you are in a subfolder, for instance:

```
http://server/sites/xxx/Pages/Somepage.aspx
```

then you can do this:

```
../_layouts/MyProject/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod
```

the .. will take you up one folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In effect what you said is correct but unfortunately does not apply in my case. In fact, as you may already know, the layouts directory is a virtual directory that is mapped to every web site in sharepoint. Furthermore my site is exactly a site collection that has, as a root path, exactly [http://server/sites/xxx](http://server/sites/xxx). So I am using it correctly when starting with `/`

Comment: Is the URL you intend to get as a result `http://server/sites/xxx/_Layouts...` or `http://server/_Layouts`.  If it is the former then I believe my answer is valid.  To test it, create a simple link that goes to the same path that you are passing ajax, see what URL ends up in the address bar, this is the URL that is being resolved by AJAX as well.  I think you may end up needing some modification to this url.  Whether you can make some assumptions and use something like `../` etc. or do something more complex with either javascript or codebehind to get the proper site root.

Comment: I have resolved using `<%= SPContext.Current.Site.Url %>` that give me the first part of the url (`http://server/sites/xxx`). Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: No problem.  That's essentially what I meant by "you may need to use the codebehind to inject the path", except I'm usually not allowed inline code so I mentioned codebehind.

Comment: Right. That's the reason why I am going to accept this answer as good and valid. I had to use inline code because our design does not expect to use code behind at all, essentially using jQuery, jTemplate and Validate. Ciao